# How to run single file test in quasar testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, quasar

I have test code to run in quasar project, but dont want to run all tests.
so I tried several below commands,  still run all test files.

```
quasar test --unit jest -t "demo/demo.spec.js"
quasar test --unit jest --spec "demo/demo.spec.js"
quasar test --unit jest -i "demo/demo.spec.js"
```

what do I have to do?

Comment: This will help [`JEST CLI`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can skip Quasar CLI and use the scripts available in package.json.

```
npm run test:unit test/jest/__tests__/App.spec.js
```

A better approach for a quicker *test and develop* process would be using the `test:unit:watch` script then filtering for a filename pattern.

```
npm run test:unit:watch
#press p, then type the desired file pattern
```

[image: Jest Watch Usage]

Comment: Another way: `npx jest demo`

Answer (score 0):

you can use jest command to test files you are targeting with regex.

quasar doesn't have any simgle file test, it will test all files with any cmd.

The word after -i doesn't mean file name, but it is regex pattern meaning "/demo/i"

```
jest -i demo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also test separate files using the Majestic UI plugin, which you can select as an option when installing jest.

Start Majestic with the command `npm run test:unit:ui` which will open a localhost testing UI and from there you can test each file individually.